# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, garbage-collection, jersey, jersey-2.0

I have a tomcat 8 instance running only my jersey web-service application on a windows machine. After some time (can be hours or days) tomcat simply crashes, leaving the following log:

It looks like the error is happening in a web service because i can see `org.glassfish.jersey` in the stack trace.

But i don't know exactly why nor where this is happening. Maybe some of my services are eating a lot of memory but i don't know which one.

Is there a way to run some diagnosis to detect exactly what is the cause of this error?

```
11-Apr-2015 10:27:09.154 INFO [http-apr-8080-exec-3] org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize Initiating Jersey application, version Jersey: 2.0 2013-05-14 20:07:34...
11-Apr-2015 19:20:59.447 WARNING [http-apr-8080-exec-5] null.null Attempt to release single request processing resources has failed.
 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedKeySet.iterator(LinkedHashMap.java:539)
    at java.util.HashSet.iterator(HashSet.java:172)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.DescriptorImpl.hashCode(DescriptorImpl.java:481)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.hashCode(SystemDescriptor.java:729)
    at java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:338)
    at java.util.HashMap.get(HashMap.java:556)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope$Instance.put(RequestScope.java:491)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.findOrCreate(RequestScope.java:158)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2203)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:579)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.IterableProviderImpl.get(IterableProviderImpl.java:87)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.release(ServerRuntime.java:539)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:324)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:227)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:198)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:946)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:323)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:372)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:335)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)

11-Apr-2015 19:22:09.935 SEVERE [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run Unexpected death of background thread ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]
 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

Comment: take jmap dump and try to map the instances consuming lots of memory with your code

Comment: GC takes too long.  This might be because of swapping.  Does the JVM process use more memory than is physically available?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen GC overrhead doesn't mean the GC took too long.  It means the JVM is spending too much time GCing which is likely due to memory growing to the max limit allowed.

Comment: @JohnVint And what triggers the exception?  Takes too long with too little gain.

Comment: So how to see what the JVM is garbage collecting? I mean, can i see what objects it is collecting that makes it take too long?

Comment: you can use visualvm or hprof for allocation profiling.

Comment: What exact version of Jersey are you using?  There are some known memory leaks that have recently been fixed

Comment: @jwells131313 I am using jersey v2.0